# Get the last row that a value appears

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-drive

Let me see if I can explain what I need to do.
I have a sheet in Google Drive and in it there is many tabs, each tab is for a city and for the number of Covid cases in this city.
In some tabs I have daily updates, in others the updates come 3 times a day. For example:
**TAB NEWYORK**

- 20/04   10
- 21/04   12

**TAB WASHINGTON**

- 20/04   5
- 20/04   7
- 21/04   8
- 21/04   8

In a different tab I need the sum of values at the end of the day, e.g. 20th=17, 21th=20.
I cannot combine always the same, because in one case the last value of the 20th will be on second line, in other tab will be on first, in other it might be on fifth.
What I need is some kind of formula/command that always get the last row of each value in the first column(date) and get the values from the same row in other columns:
*If the last line of 22/04 is on A9, it gets the value of B9 - if in other tab is on A4, get B4 value*.
Is there such a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

In the formula below - dates are in column A, totals are in column B and the search term (date of interest) is in C2. The match returns the first result, the countif determines the number of matches then the two are added together and subtract 1 to get the correct index row in column B.

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,FALSE)+COUNTIF(A:A,C2)-1,1)
```

[image: Formula example]

Comment: I'm sorry. It didn't work.Someone helped me doing other way, but this generated an error

Comment: The formula works fine on the data I tested, if you can let me know the error it generated so I can have a look at it. I know it is solved but I would like to see why this solution failed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. 
I don't know the entire formula because other person solved it(when I find out, I will put in here) but it was used PROCV function.